# Is there any indication in the spark UI about caching operation?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm calling `cache()` but I couldn't find any indication for it in the Spark UI. I also see nothing in the Storage section.

Can I see any indication of this? At the moment, I'm not sure anything is happening when I use the cache. Using PySpark if it's matter

Comment: Are you checking your spark ui when your spark job is running, or after it is finished, from my experience the storage tab is empty after the job is finished and only available when the job is running.

Comment: You can use the `is_cached` method which returns True if the DataFrame or RDD is cached and False otherwise. Alternatively, you can make use of the `storageLevel` method as well.

Comment: note - simply calling `cache()` doesn't cache the dataframe. it will cache it during the upcoming action. spark is lazy.